# How can I format a float to a certain number of decimal and integer digits?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to format a float in Ruby to exactly four digits, including the decimal.

For instance:

```
1 => 01.00
2.4 => 02.40
1.4455 => 01.45
```

Right now, I am trying to format the float as follows:

```
str_result = " %.2f " %result
```

Which successfully limits the decimal places to two.

I'm also aware of:

```
str_result = " %2d " %result
```

Which succesfully turns `1` into `01`, but loses the decimal places.

I tried to combine these like so:

```
str_result = " %2.2f " %result
```

to no apparent effect. It has the same results as `%.2f`.

Is there a way to force Ruby to format the string into this four digit format?

Comment: Are all numbers less than `100`?

Comment: @sawa In my case, yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf('%05.2f', value)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

The key is that the format is `width . precision`, where `width` indicates a minimum width for the entire number, not just the integer portion.

```
def print_float(value)
  sprintf('%05.2f', value)
end
print_float(1)
# => "01.00" 
print_float(2.4)
# => "02.40" 
print_float(1.4455)
# => "01.45"
```

Comment: Yup, that's it: `[ 1, 2.4, 1.4455 ].map { |amount| sprintf('%05.2f', amount) } #=> ["01.00", "02.40", "01.45"]`.  The key is that the format is *width* `.` *precision*, where width indicates a minimum width for the entire number, not just the integer portion. Also note the use of the `0` as a prefix to zero-fill.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, you can also use the [number_with_precision](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) helper. Example:

```
<%= number_with_precision(my_float, precision: 2) %>
```